# 20140524(arrayList) to 24/05/2014(Arraylist)?in java

Tags: java, date, arraylist

How to convert int type of  date ArrayList to date format like 24/05/2014.?in java

getLoyalityExpiryDate() this method returns arraylist ,from this type of int arralist dates to type of String arraylist dates transformation I need .please help me.

example:20140524(arrayList)  to 24/05/2014(Arraylist)?in java

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a date arraylist?

Comment: I have to convert 20140524 to 24/05/2014 format but dynamically .
Based on customer number transaction dates can be many.

Comment: Those look like strings.  Where are the arraylists?

Comment: yeah int to String  only.....
I have taken Array list bcz customer may have many transaction dates
the above  mentioned format is required one.

Comment: But I don't see ints either.  Do you just need to transform the _string_ `"20140524"` into the _string_ `"24/05/2014"`?

Comment: 20140524 it is type of int ....

Comment: getLoyalityExpiryDate(); returns arraylist ....
from this type of int  arraylist  to String type of array list .

Comment: Assuming all ints are exactly 6 digits: `List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(); for (int d: getLoyaltyExpiryDate()) {String s = Integer.toString(d); result.add(s.substring(6) + "/" + s.substring(4,6) + "/" + s.substring(0,4));}`  Better would be to parse and format the dates using a `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

> Split the string to the corresponding day month and year.

```
String year = expDate1.substring(0, 4);

String month = expDate1.substring(4, 6) ;

String day = expDate1.substring(6,8) ;

Date date= new Date(year, month, date);
```

Comment: Thanks...But I Have getLoyalityExpiryDate();

Comment: getLoyalityExpiryDate() method returns Arraylist...how to convert from arraylist?

Comment: I guess you want to iterate and apply to each value.!! You cant like update all the values without iteration.